# Can't access object property when callback is invoked

Tags: javascript, oop

```
function Push(apiInstance) {
    this.api = apiInstance; // If I alert() here this is a valid object
    this.pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

    if ( device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' )
    {
        this.pushNotification.register(
            this.successHandler,
            this.errorHandler, {
                "senderID":"",
                "ecb":"onNotificationGCM"
            });
    }
    else
    {
        this.pushNotification.register(
            this.tokenHandler,
            this.errorHandler, {
                "badge":"true",
                "sound":"true",
                "alert":"true",
                "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
            });
    }
}

Push.prototype.tokenHandler = function (token) {
    this.api.registerDevice(token); // Suddenly this.api is undefined
};

var push = new Push(/* in my production code this is a valid object */);
```

I know that `apiInstance` is valid as if I alert the instance in the constructor it shows as an object. For some reason when the tokenHandler callback is invoked `this.api` is suddenly undefined.. any ideas why? OOP in JavaScript is so frustrating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
this.pushNotification.register(
    this.tokenHandler,
    this.errorHandler, ...);
```

You are essentially passing the function object `tokenHandler` and it doesn't know that it was bound to the current object. So when it is invoked by the `register` function, as it is not bound to any object, JavaScript will pass the global object as `this` (in Strict mode it will pass `undefined`). To avoid that, you need to explicitly bind the current object with the function object, with [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like this

```
this.pushNotification.register(
    this.tokenHandler.bind(this),
    this.errorHandler.bind(this), ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this:

```
this.tokenHandler
```

is just a function itself, and the function does not know anything about where it belongs to and what it's context should be. To work this around you can apply the following:

```
var self = this;
this.pushNotification.register(
    function (token) {
        self.tokenHandler(token);
    },
```

This use of a closure will ensure that `tokenHandler` is called with a `self` context, which is an instance of a `Push`

Answer (score 0):

That is because scoping in javascript is done on the functions level.

In this peace of code:

```
function Push(apiInstance) {
    this.api = apiInstance; // If I alert() here this is a valid object
}
```

"this" - is the scope of the function Push. so, you can try to do next:

```
var api = {};
function Push(apiInstance) {
    api = apiInstance; // If I alert() here this is a valid object
    this.pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

    if ( device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' )
    {
        this.pushNotification.register(
            this.successHandler,
            this.errorHandler, {
                "senderID":"",
                "ecb":"onNotificationGCM"
            });
    }
    else
    {
        this.pushNotification.register(
            this.tokenHandler,
            this.errorHandler, {
                "badge":"true",
                "sound":"true",
                "alert":"true",
                "ecb":"onNotificationAPN"
            });
    }
}

Push.prototype.tokenHandler = function (token) {
    api.registerDevice(token); // Suddenly this.api is undefined
};

var push = new Push(/* in my production code this is a valid object */);
```

In this code api - will be variable not in scope of the function, but in "global scope" for the function Push.